# Find process id by command used by the process and kill it

Tags: command-line, bash, ffmpeg

So sometimes ffmpeg hangs and i need to look into system monitor and the command used by it to find the specific process and kill it.

Is there an easier way / bash script to just say ./scipt blabla where blabla is the part of the command used in ffmpeg -i ..... blabla and when it's found it should be killed or someting which returns the PID so i can manually just pkill the process id? instead of manually scrolling trough all the active ffmpeg processes and commands used by them.

I got it working by:

```
ps -Af | grep '/root/bin/ffmpeg.*blabla' | grep ? | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo kill -15
```

But what if the command gives me 2 pids?

Comment: If you are running only one `ffmpeg` command (each time), you can look for it with the following command line, `ps -A | grep ffmpeg`; Otherwise you can let `grep` look for something more specific, the 'blabla', for example a file name. The first field of the output is the PID of the process.

Comment: `ps -Af | grep 'ffmpeg.*blabla'` and ignore the last hit which shows the `grep` command

Comment: @sudodus:  Or `ps -Af | grep '[f]fmpeg.*blabla'`

Comment: You get the header of the `ps` list with the following command: `ps -Af|head -n1`

Comment: I tried ps -A | grep ffmpeg and i gor the processid's but i also tried ps -Af | grep 'ffmpeg.*blabla' no result. the blabla part is part of a command line used by ffmpeg.

Comment: ps -Af | grep '/root/bin/ffmpeg.*blabla' got me the procesid and whole command.

Comment: but also another process from pts/6 which is not relivant
I added | awk '{print $2}' behind and this ends up with only the PID but 1 pid is correct the other is from another process but is irrelivant. Seems to be the TTY. I need the TTY with ? So I also added grep ? and that seems to do the trick

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the process id(s) of `ffmpeg` command:

```
pgrep -x ffmpeg
```

But you can directly kill it using `pkill`:

```
pkill -x ffmpeg
```

Specify the signal (default is SIGTERM), e.g.

```
pkill -x -9 ffmpeg
```

---

Why `-x`:
`pgrep`/`pkill` matches a pattern, so unless you add `-x` option (exact match), it will match also `thisisnotffmpeg`.

You might need `-f` to match the full command instead of the process name only, e.g. if you have multiple `ffmpeg` command running from which you only want to kill specific ones ending with `blabla`:

```
pkill -f '^ffmpeg.*blabla$'
```

Comment: You might need -f option to each: `pgrep -xf 'ffmpeg.*blabla'`

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -Af | grep '/root/bin/ffmpeg.*blabla' | grep ? | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo kill -15
```

made it work! but what if I end up with two pids? and Easies would be ./script blabla where bla bla is placed in the code and it is being executed.

Seems to also work when result is multiple pids :P

Final script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# $1 is process name

if [ $# -ne 1 ];
then
    echo "Invalid number of arguments"
    exit 0
fi

grepme="/root/bin/ffmpeg.*"$1""

ffmpegrunning=$(ps -Af | grep "$grepme" | grep ? | awk '{print $2}')

if [ -z "$ffmpegrunning" ]
then
    echo "There is no active " $1 " process..."
else
thisrunning=$(ps -Af | grep "$grepme" | grep ? | awk -v FS="(/input/ffmpeg|.ts)" '{print $3}')
ffmpegrunning=$(ps -Af | grep "$grepme" | grep ? | awk '{print $2}'| xargs sudo kill -15)
echo $ffmpegrunning " " $thisrunning "rebooted..."

fi
```

Only thing is when it reboots more than one instance the echo is summed up instead of having an enter in behind like:
12123 2222 bla blabla

i would like
12123 bla rebooted
2222 blabla rebooted